# Display Product Image from WooCommerce plugin using a custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I'm trying to learn WordPress and developing custom plugins. I'm trying to make a custom plugin where it will display just the Product Image from the Woocommerce plugin to the page. I have 1 product, and I've been reading documentation and haven't really found anything that explains it clearly or works. This is all I have now

```
<?php   
    $gallery_shortcode = '[gallery id="' .intval($post->$post_parent).'"]';
    print apply_filters('the_content', $gallery_shortcode);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the question is not very clear, so I'll try to guess what you're looking for.

You can "get" a product image with this function:

```
woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
```

If you need it in a custom single product PHP template, simply:

```
echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
```

If you need it in a shortcode inside the single product page:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_image', 'bbloomer_product_image_shortcode' );

function bbloomer_product_reviews_shortcode() {    
   return woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
}
```

...and then use [product_image] shortcode to show the image

Comment: So basically the task asks to create a plugin, and with this plugin it will need to generate shortcode that will display the main image of the product you created in the Woocommerce setup portion that was done earlier.

Comment: I don't know if that helps narrow it done a bit more